# how to get a row number for each group in report?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oraclereports

i am making a report that getting employees for each group and i need to get a row number for each  employee in each department group

```
select rownum,e.empno, e.ename, e.sal, e.comm, e.deptno, d.dname 
  from emp e
  left join dept d on emp.deptno = dept.deptno
 order by deptno;
```

Comment: What defines each group?

Comment: i need to give each department's employees a new row number

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp.deptno ORDER BY emp.ename) rn,
    emp.empno,
    emp.ENAME,
    emp.SAL,
    emp.COMM,
    emp.DEPTNO,
    dept.dname
FROM emp
LEFT JOIN dept
    ON emp.deptno = dept.deptno
ORDER BY
    emp.deptno;
```

Note that you never provided logic for what should decide the ordering of each employee within a department.  In the absence of this, I have used the employee name.  If you want some other ordering, then just modify the `ORDER BY` clause in the call to `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: thanks so much 
but i did it in easy way
in data module 
i put a new summery column 
and i modify its property  function to count  and reset at the group i made before